# Renaming pdf files to include the parentfolder name as the prefix, and including a unique suffix

Tags: script, rename, batch-rename, files-folders, naming

Please can you help. How can I rename pdf files to include the parentfolder name as the prefix, and adding `DRAFT` as a suffix?

For example, for parent folder name `\ABCDEF`:

- `xyc123.pdf`
- `fgh456.pdf`

I would like it to look like this `\abcdef`:

- `abcdefDRAFT.pdf`
- `abcdefDRAFT.pdf`

Each pdf is always unique, and each folder is always unique.
I just need the corresponding `.pdfs` in each folder to match the folder name.

I am new to scripting, and I would like to write and run the script using notepad
(I am not able to download any 3rd party software). Thank you.

Comment: I guess that you are looking for a Windows solution since you mention Notepad ?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I just amend it slightly, I only need to create a DRAFT for both pdf files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For command line in same folder (top-level folder tree):

---

```bat
cd /d "c:\folder_target\" & for /f tokens^=* %i in ('dir/b/s/a:-d')do ren "%~fi" "%~niDraft%~xi"
```

---

For bat/cmd file:

---

```bat
@echo off 

cd /d "c:\folder_target\"
for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir/b/s/a:-d')do ren "%%~fi" "%%~niDraft%~xi"
```

---

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Cd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [`ren /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)